# No WiFi found on numerous Linux distros (testing Linux distros)

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, drivers, live-usb

I've been noticing a really odd pattern when I'm testing Linux distributions that I may consider installing in the future. I'm unsure how to exactly put this due to its nature: but for every Linux distro I try (***also might be worth noting that I'm using a Ventoy Multi-boot USB drive for this and maybe therefore isn't the most complete way to perform testing?***) seems to not have Wifi support/ Wifi adapter recognition.

I have noticed a few patterns in my distro testing (**all performed in live sessions**):

- Every Arch-based distro recognizes WiFi (I have tested Manjaro, Garuda, Endeavour, and ArcoLinux)
- Every Ubuntu-based distro does not recognize my adapter (**with the exception of POP!_OS**)
- Every Debian-based distro doesn't either (**MX Linux and Nitrux are exceptions**)

I'm tempted to say it's an Ubuntu thing about my wifi card, but I'm not too sure because the pattern of Wifi On-Off seems to random; but I thought it was a BIOS/UEFI issue. Can anybody help me figure out what's going on here?

Thank you! (**WiFi adapter is Realtek RTL8821CE**)

Comment: You might need to install/update the device-specific firmware package

Comment: Distros which work might contain a newer kernel. As always with Linux the newer the kernel the more hardware devices it supports. And of course this device might need firmware files.

Comment: So meaning if I do decide to install any given one, would I need to install the system through like ethernet and then install the firmware packages necessary?

Comment: What do you mean by "recognizing" the adapter? And can you post the output of `lspci`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a third-party driver which is not present in the upstream kernel. Arch [includes it in the AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rtl8821ce-dkms-git), but only because they're adding the source code manually. If you want to use this on Debian, you'll need to [compile the source code yourself](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce). Unfortunately, Debian has only supports the RTW variant, in my opinion improperly closing [the bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=917941) which asked for RTL8821CE, not RTW8821CE.

See also https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=367887

Comment: AUR isn't exactly "include it" though. AFAIK, even official Arch ISO does not / cannot (as in, the image building scripts does not have facility for that; let alone policy) include AUR packages. If by recognized the OP really means it's working (instead of just being listed with model name or so in `lspci`), then it's probably not a rtl8821ce (maybe rtl8821ae).

Comment: @TomYan Odd. Well, if it's the RTL8821CE, then even if it's recognized, it's not supported out of the box. I commented on the question to ask for the lspci output, which should clear things up.